# Kislev and the letter Samech

Tags: chanuka, mysticism-kabbalah, aleph-bet-letters, arizal, months

I have seen somewhere that Kislev and the letter Samech are connected to each other. The sefer I saw it in, quoted the Likkutei Shas of the Arizal. Does anyone know what it says? And is there any other reason why there is a connection?

Comment: The Benei Yisaschar always explains the connection between the letter and the month. Also Reb Tzadok sometimes.

Comment: It is mentioned in perek hei of Sefer Yetzirah

Comment: @TheGRAPKE if you can try and find it online I will be really grateful. Please if you do find it post it as an answer. :>

Comment: @Russell Done, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the Likkutei Shas of the Arizal says, but as per the second clause of your question asking if there are any other reasons for a connection, there is a famous piece in the fifth chapter of Sefer Yetzira which goes through the alef beis.

It writes somewhat cryptically:

> המליך אות ס' בשינה וקשר לו כתר וצרפן זה בזה וצר בהם קשת בעולם וכסלו בשנה וקבה בנפש זכר ונקבה
>
> ***He produced the letter Samech**,  predominant in sleep, tied on it a crown, combined this one and that one, and formed Sagittarius (the astrological sign / mazal of the month) in the world, **Kislev in the year**, and the stomach of person male and female.*

According to [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4556275/jewish/12-Facts-About-the-Month-of-Kislev-You-Should-Know.htm) it can be understood as follows:

> *The previous month, Cheshvan, has been associated with the biting scorpion and the letter nun, which stands for nofel, fall. This month, **we are thus uplifted with the letter samech, which means “support.”***

[Rabbi Yitzchak Ginsburgh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Ginsburgh) helps develop our understanding of this esoteric statement in the Sefer Yetzira [here](https://www.inner.org/times/kislev/kislev.htm) and goes through all the clauses of the text. Some of the highlights as they pertain to your question, read as follows:

> The miracle of Chanukah reflects the active trust of the Hasmoneans (the Maccabees) in God that drove them to stand up and fight against the Hellenistic Seleucid kingdom (and its culture). **Kislev’s sense is sleep. Sleep too is connected with trust and reflects the passive trust that we all have that God’s Providence always watches over all**...The name of the letter samech implies “support.” **The experience of feeling supported corresponds to the trust and confidence in Divine providence associated with Kislev**, as described above. In the same vein, in Psalms we find the expression, “God supports (סוֹמֵךְ) all the fallen and lifts up all the bent over”([Tehillim 145:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.145.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Also, “Should he fall, he will not be cast aside, for God supports (סוֹמֵךְ) his hand” ([Tehillim 37:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.37.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).
>
> The letter samech is shaped like a circle, representing G-d’s omnipresence and universal providence. The “great circle,” representing God’s Infinite light is explained in Chassidut to reflect His right arm embracing (and supporting, from beneath) with great, infinite love, all of reality, as is said, “And from beneath, the arms of the universe” -([Deuteronomy 33:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.33.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).
>
> The zodiac symbol of Kislev is the bow (קֶשֶׁת), which means both an archer’s bow and a rainbow. The latter relates clearly with the theme of Chanukah as the archer’s bow of the Maccabees. It symbolizes their active trust in God to fight against the Hellenistic culture that ruled the world at the time...The archer’s bow is a projection (or, one might say it is shot, like an arrow out of a bow) of the rainbow—the sign of the covenant made between God and creation never to destroy the world again and a sign of peace—which pervades the end of the previous month, Cheshvan. **Graphically, the two bows—the rainbow and the archer’s bow—are two half circles, that when joined together form the shape of the circular letter samech, the letter of the month of Kislev**.

Answer (score 2):

The [Pri Tzadik](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Tzadik%2C_Rosh_Chodesh_Kislev.5?lang=bi) writes on Rosh Chodesh Kislev the following:

> בסי״צ המליך אות ס׳ בשינה כו׳ וכסלו בשנה. באותיות דר״ע אות ס׳. **א״ת סמך
> אלא סומך מך זה הקב״ה שהוא סומך מכים נופלים שנ׳ סומך ה׳ לכל הנופלים
> כו׳. ד״א סמך אלו ישראל שסומכין להם תמיד זכות אבותיהם אברהם יצחק ויעקב
> ויוסף משה ואהרן ודוד ושלמה וכו׳. והיינו דאות ס׳ מורה על אור מקיף ואות
> ס׳ ראשונה שבתורה בתיבת הוא הסובב.** ובכל מקום שנזכר האות בראשונה בתורה
> מורה על שורש החיים של זה האות וכמו שמצינו (ב״ק נה.) לענין אות ט׳ הואיל
> ופתח בו הכתוב לטובה תחלה. וכן באות ס׳ פתח תחלה הוא הסובב שהוא מקיף.
> **וכן צורת האות מקיף**. ואמר קודם שהקב״ה סמך סומך מך. והיינו ישראל וכמ״ש
> (ב״ר פ׳ ע״א) כ״מ שנזכר דל עני ואביון בישראל הכ׳ מדבר. ואח״כ אמר דישראל
> הוא האויר שבתוך אות ס׳. והמקיף רועי ישראל ז׳ רועים שהס מרכבה לז׳
> המדות. וכן דרש אח״כ סמך זו ירושלי׳ כו׳ והיינו שהפנימיות הוא ירושלים
> והרים סביב לה. הרים אלו אבות קדושת תאבות. דאברהם קראו הר יצחק שדה
> ויעקב קראו בית כמ״ש בגמ׳ (פסחים פח.) וכן כשדרש סמך אלו ישראל המכוון
> ג״כ שישראל הם פנימיות הס׳ האויר שבאות ס׳. ורועי ישראל המקיפין להם.
> וחשב שם באותיות דר״ע זכותן של אברהם ויצחק במזרח סביב להם שנ׳ מי העיר
> ממזרח צדק ע״ש והיינו שזה נאמר על אברהם. ובגמ׳ (שבת קנו:) מה דעתיך דקאי
> צדק במערב מהדרנא ומוקמינא לי׳ במזרח כו׳ והיינו שהוא אאע״ה סבר שהוא
> הסוף צדק מלכיתא קדישא מדה אחרונה. מהדרנא ומוקמינא לי׳ במזרח שממנו
> יתחיל עיקר זריחת האור וכמ״ש בב״ר יהי אור זה אברהם. ויצחק ג״כ במזרח
> שהוא עיקר זריחת האור של ישראל שהיה הראשון שנימול לח׳. והיינו שנולד
> מתולדה ישראל. ואח״כ א׳ זכותן של יעקב ויוסף במערב שנ׳ ודמות וגו׳ פני
> אדם זה דמות יעקב שחקוקה על כה״כ. דמות שור זה דמות יוסף שנ׳ בכור שורו
> הדר לו כו׳. והענין דכ׳ והארץ הדום רגלי והיינו בהמ״ק ששם השראת השכינה
> ונקרא בגמ׳ (מכות כד סע״א) בית הדום רגלי אלהינו וכ״ה במ״ר (סוף איכה)
> והיינו בקודש הקדשים שהוא במערב וגם השכינה במערב כמ״ש (ב״ב כה.) וע״כ
> חשב זכותן של אברהם ויצחק ממזרח שמהם תחלת זריחת האור. ויעקב ויוסף ממערב
> שהם עיקר כנס״י שכל ישראל נקראו בית יעקב ושארית יוסף ע״ש יוסף כמ״ש (ב״ר
> פ׳ עא) והיינו דיעקב מדתו אמת. והוא מרכבה לאות ו׳ דאיקרי אות אמת כמ״ש
> (זוה״ק ר״פ ויקרא) ויוסף ו׳ זעירא ו׳ המילוי. ויעקב הבריח התיכון וגו׳ אל
> הקצה. והיינו מכ״ע למדת כנס״י. ויוסף נקרא כלכל שעל ידו ההשפעה וההמשכה
> לכנס״י. וכ״ה בזוה״ק (ח״א קפב ב) ותרווייהו כחדא אזלי. ודא רזא דאת ו״ו
> דאזלי תרווייהו כחדא כו׳ ע״ש וז״ש יעקב פני אדם ויוסף דמות שור. אף שיש
> ג״כ פני נשר ופני אריה. אך הוא עפמ״ש בגמ׳ (חגיגה יג:) דפני השור יחזקאל
> ביקש רחמים עליו והפכו לכרוב כו׳ היינו פני כרוב היינו פני אדם. אפי
> רברבי ואפי זוטרי. והיינו דמות יעקב את ו׳ ויוסף ו׳ המילוי כאמור. ואמר
> זכותם של משה ואהרן בדרום כו׳ זכותם של דוד ושלמה בצפון כו׳. והוא עפמ״ש
> (ב״ב כה:) הרוצה שיחכים ידרים ושיעשיר יצפין כו׳ שלחן בצפון ומנורה
> בדרום. ומשה ואהרן רבותיהם של ישראל משה רבינו הוריד התושב״כ ואהרן שורש
> התושבע״פ דכ׳ כי שפתי כהן ישמרו דעת ותורה יבקשו מפיהו. **ושניהם בחכמה
> בדרום דמנורה בדרום להאיר לישראל**. ודוד ושלמה מלכי ישראל שולחן בצפון וזר
> השלחן מרמז לשולחן מלכים כמ״ש (יומא עב: ופירש״י שם). וחשב דוד ושלמה
> דשניהם אות ה׳ רק דוד שהקים עולה של תשובה (מו״ק טז:) ה׳ עלאה בינה כמש״נ
> ולבבו יבין ושב. ושלמה ה׳ תתאה דהות סיהרא באשלמותא וזכה לכל חכמה תתאה
> חכמת שלמה. ובאותיות דר״ע אמר בטעם שדוד ושלמה מן הצפון ששניהם נתנבאו על
> מפן שכרן של צדיקים שבג״ע שהוא נתון בצפון כו׳. דוד נתנבא כשראה טובה של
> ג״ע מה רב טובך אשר צפנת ליריאך. שלמה נתנבא ואמר יצפון לישרים תושי׳
> ע״ש. והיינו ששניהם נתנבאו על האור הראשון שנגנז לצדיקים לע״ל וזהו אשר
> צפנת ליריאך. ולעתיד כ׳ אומר לצפון תני וגו׳ ובזוה״ק (ח״ג קעג ב) לזמנא
> דאתי קרי קב״ה לצפון ויימא לי׳ בך יהיבת כל טיבו וכל אגר טוב לבני כו׳
> והיינו אור הראשון הנגנז לצדיקים לע״ל. וחשב ד׳ רוחות עפמ״ש בזוה״ק (ח״ב
> קכז סע״א קפ רע״א) ע״ש. וכאן נחשב סמך אלו ישראל היינו הפנימיות המוקף
> הוא ס׳ והמקיף זכות האבות והרועים. והוא עדמ״ש בזוה״ק (שם רד א) שבת ש׳
> רזא דג׳ אבהן ובת מתעטרא בהו. וכבר אמרנו דכן יעקב ויוסף כחדא אינון רזא
> דאת ו״ו. וכן מוסף שבת נחשב (בזוה״ח תולדות) נגד יוסף דהתוספת קדושה דשבת
> ע״י יוסף. ואומרים קריבו שושבינין שהם משה ואהרן כמ״ש (מ״ר ומד״ת עקב)
> שהם ג״כ שורש קדושת שבת ודוד ושלמה ה׳ עלאה ותתאה שהוא שבת עלאה ושבת
> תתאה וזוכין ישראל בשבת לכל קדושת הרועים. ואמר בספר יצירה המליך אות ס׳
> בשינה דכבר אמרנו דשמות החדשים מורים על קדושת החודש. כמו שדרשו תשרי
> תשרי ותשבוק ותכפר על חובי עמך (כשנ״ת מא׳ ב). ושם כסלו הוא עפמש״נ כי ה׳
> יהיה בכסלך ושמר רגלך מלכד ופירש״י מירוש׳ בדברים שאתה כסיל בהם. והיינו
> אף בשינה אף כשהאדם הולך בטל דיושב בשל כישן דמי וכמ״ש (ע״ז יח:) אלך
> ואתגרה בשינה ת״ל ובתורתו יהגה וגו׳ והיינו דשינה הוא כשהולך בטל. **וכאן
> כסלו בו׳ קוב״ה שהוא סמך האור מקיף סומך ה׳ לכל הנופלים.** **וכן סמ״ך אלו
> ישראל שמוקפים מהסייעתות מהז׳ רועים שהם מרכבה לז׳ המדות עם ה׳ עלאה בינה
> והוא דהמע״ה שהקים עולה של תשובה וכמו שאמרנו וזה קדושת החודש.** **ואח״כ
> בסוף החודש זוכין להאור נהורא עלאה האור כי טוב ובו נס חנוכה.** **ואז ישראל
> המקיף שנעשים כנס״י הס׳ בינה שמקיפים להאור חכמה והוא מקום שבעלי תשובה
> עומדין שאין צדיקים גמורים עומדים שם** כמ״ש (ברכות לד:) והיא שער הנ׳ מנ׳
> שערי בינה. והיינו שזוכין לסוד הדעת וזוכין למש״נ ואוהב את יעקב אהבה בלא
> טעם. וליעקב נתגלה בחלום והנה הוי״ה נצב עליו דיעקב אע״ה סוד הדעת וכמ״ש
> בזוה״ק (ח״ב יד סע״ב). ושלמה שקראו הקב״ה ידידיה זכה לכל חכמה תתאה
> בחלום. **וזה קדושת החודש שישתדל האדם לזכות לתושבע״פ שהוא מטלא דעתיקא.
> ואז זוכין מצד השי״ת אף בשינה סומך ה׳ לכל הנופלים.** כי ה׳ יהיה בכסלך

Summary, approximately:

The meaning of the Hebrew letters follows their shape. The *samech* is round and represents the sphere of Godliness in which we operate.

Because of this, the *samech* also represents Hashem's ability to support people no matter how far they have fallen, because relative to the external sphere (in which we operate), we are always able to be rebonded to the source of holiness.

That is why Chanukah falls in Kislev (whose letter is *samech*), because the Jews had fallen very far under the Hellenist influence, and the light that brought them back (of the menorah) was a beam from this surrounding sphere.

Comment: Great answer! Perhaps bold some of the relevant hebrew text so people can see the highlights in the Hebrew. Kol tuv

Comment: @Dov Done, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the Ari wrote in [Likutei Shas](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19643&st=&pgnum=47&hilite=):

> "ס הוא בזר"ת של יד שמאל בפרק אמצעי ומולך בשינה והולך בצינור מת"ת להו"ד וניתן לבנימין וברא מזל קשת בעולם וחודש כסליו בשנה והקיבה בנפש והוא מן העשיריות."

My translation: Samech is in the pinkie of the left hand in the middle joint and rules in the sleep and travels the pipe from Tiferet to Hod and is given to Binyamin and created the astrological sign [mazal] of the bow [Sagittarius] and the month of Kislev in the year and the stomach in the nefesh and he is from the tenths."

The context is the parallelization of all of the letters to different parts of the hands. I have no idea what the rest of that means.

Comment: Most likely tiferes not talmud torah.

Comment: עולם שנה נפש http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9 tenths is quite simply a multiple of ten.

Comment: @interested I didn't see anything in your link about עשיריות. Also, while תפארת is also likely, I'm not sure why it would be made into an acronym.

Comment: @interested Okay I edited that in.

Comment: @Mordechai Okay I edited that in.